# Given three points on a circle, finding a fourth one on the same circle

Tags: geometry, circles

Is there any geometric construction for discovering a fourth point when three non-collinear points are given?

Comment: Try perpendicular bisectors between your three points to find the centre of the circle.  Then draw the circle and you have all the other points

Comment: @Henry Why are you giving away a solid outline of the entire solution in the comment section?

Comment: @Arthur Feel free to answer yourself using my hints or another method.

Comment: @Henry My point is: "Avoid answering questions in comments" is written inside the actual comment box, and you decide to go directly against that. I was inquiring as to how you came to the conclusion that that's an OK thing to do.

Comment: Just realized my question is trivial. I am removing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect any two line segments from three dots.
Make the perpendicular bisectors of both line segments.
The point on which the perpendicular bisectors meet is the center of the circle with the three points we started with as points on the circumference.

Why though?
Any point on the perpendicular bisector of a line segment AB is equidistant to both the end points A and B. When you take a second line segment BC, any point on the perpendicular bisector of BC is equidistant from B and C. So, the point where the perpendicular bisectors of AB and BC meet will be equidistant to A and B, and also to B and C.
Thus, all the points are equidistant from the point. This happens in the circumference of a circle.

You can now mark the fourth point easily.